# Magmi tutorials & Disadvnatages of magmi

Tags: magento, magmi

when i searched in google, i found lot of magmi documentation.

but I want to know best documentation for magmi , so i can save my time.

also what and all disadvantages of uploading products through magmi.

please help me to get some links & tutorials

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: How can I import products images for multi-store, may i know csv header columns

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can find all magmi settings and tutorials here

http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Main_Page

**Advantage of Magmi:**

- It provides decent speed compared to Dataflow (depending on server
  config & number of attributes, 70-100 rows/sec is standard magmi
  speed).
- It supports Dataflow export CSVs file & also some enhanced
  CSV syntax for dealing with custom options import & media gallery
  import.
- it works for multistore
- It supports remote image urls for    image    related attributes (in
  this case, speed is affected by image       download)
- It also provides Generic SQL Datasource Plugin that enable    getting
  data to be imported into magento from another legacy database
  instead of CSV.
- Can handle configurables (through configurables    plugin)
- Can handle related, upsell & cross-sell (using Relater &
  upsell/cross-sell plugin)

**Disadvantage of Magmi:**

- cannot handle downloable nor bundled product types yet

Comment: i will check that. we placed a csv file under var/import directory.

but still we are getting mesage as : No csv files found in magmi page : http://prnt.sc/av0i67

Comment: Is your magmi on root folder ? means beside the var folder.

Comment: magmi in root folder.

Comment: Ok, screen shot you posted is shows that your csv file should have in `magmi/var/import` not in root `var/import`.

Comment: but there is no var sub-folder under magmi folder . we installed magmi in root directory : http://prnt.sc/av0pty & http://prnt.sc/av0pw1 .

Comment: is i need to create var/import under "magmi" folder ?

Comment: Yes, you should create var/import in your magmi folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109822/discussion-between-rohit-savaliya-and-spylh9999ggr).